# Database Design - Creating Profile based on User Type

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a requirement to show Different fields to Different User Types.

For Example, Admin UserType, show the form with 10 attributes 
             Super UserType, show the form with 2 attributes
             Normal UserType, show the form with 2 attributes

How do I design the database table such a way UserType and the attributes are dynamic ?

Raja K

Answer (score 0):

I imagine there are *some* common attributes among the users, right?  You might approach this by "supertyping" the tables.  First create a base table with the common attributes.  Something like this:

```
Users
----------
ID (PK)
Username
AccountCreatedDate
etc.
```

Any user account would have a record in this table.  Depending on whether or not it makes ongoing operations simpler you might even include a flag in the table indicating the user type.

You might then add additional tables for the other user types, where their PK is also a FK to this base table.  Something like this:

```
AdminUsers
----------
ID (PK, FK to Users)
etc.
```

That would contain the attributes specific to an admin user.  Another table would contain attributes specific to a super user.  And so on.  An added benefit here is that a single user can have multiple roles and be interpreted in multiple ways depending on the use case.  And you can have some simple compiled views in the database which make querying the table structure easier.

This would work well for a static set of user types.  If that set is going to change often during normal application usage (that is, if one of the operations of the application is that people can *add* user types) then you wouldn't want a rigid schema.

In cases like that you might make treat the fields as meta-attributes on a generic table of user properties.  So you might have your base table again:

```
Users
----------
ID (PK)
Username
UserType
etc.
```

And then you might have a generic table of properties:

```
UserProperties
----------
ID (PK)
UserID (FK to Users)
PropertyName
PropertyValue
```

This is more dynamic, but it has some drawbacks that come to mind:

1. You can't maintain data types in the database.  Everything becomes "stringly typed" and it's up to the application to interpret the types correctly.  This will result in a *ton* of defensive programming code in the application.
2. You can't maintain the schema in the database.  Things like required properties would need to be maintained by the application, the database couldn't guarantee it.  So the potential for dirtier data is higher.
3. It's more difficult to query and report on this structure.

So there are pros and cons either way, whichever approach you take is up to you and the needs of the system you're building.